# Do you know method to get the JavaFX Text node of a TextArea without using the CSS properties?

Tags: java, css, javafx, underline

I wish to find a method to get the Text node of a TextArea without using the CSS properties. The Text node of JavaFX exposes the method setUnderline(boolean) 
through which I can set the underline property of a TextArea; the TextArea, instead, doesn't expose the same method. In addition, the TextArea.getText() method returns a String instead of a Text object.
So, I solved the problem as follow:
In the code,

```
// Fields..
private final PseudoClass pseudoClass = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("underlined");
private final SimpleBooleanProperty underlinedProperty = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
private final TextArea textArea = new TextArea();

[...]

// In a method (ex. in the constructor)..
{
    textArea.setId("textArea"); 
    underlinedProperty.addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
            Node node = textArea.getScene().lookup("#textArea .text");  
            node.pseudoClassStateChanged(pseudoClass, newValue);
        }
    });
}

[...]

// The class exposes the getter method for the underlinedProperty
public SimpleBooleanProperty getUnderlinedProperty() {
    return underlinedProperty;
}
```

Now, I've create a CSS sheet with this code:

```
#textArea .text {
    /* some styles */
    -fx-underline: false;
}

#textArea .text:underlined {
    -fx-underline: true;
}
```

Finally, the above class is called in some other classes:

```
{
    'handleOfClassInPoint1'.getUnderlineProperty().set(true); // or false
}
```

The problem is the lookup() method: this method returns a not null value only if all the fx nodes were created, i.e. only after some graphical result.
I wish to find a procedure to set the underline property of a TextArea without using CSS (ex. a toggle button manages the underline property: the text of a TextArea is underlined if the toggle is selected).
Anyone can help me?
Thank you so much!

Comment: Why not apply the styles to the `TextArea`? You don't need the `Text` node. Simply use the `PseudoClass` with the `TextArea` and continue using your CSS. Then toggle the `PseudoClass` depending on the selected state of the `ToggleButton`. Possibly encapsulate all the behavior in your own `TextArea` class and expose your `underlinedProperty ` property.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not sure I've completely understood your solution, but I think I've already implemented the code as you propose.
The CSS id is set on the TextArea class and the pseudoclass changes are registered conformely to the ToggleButton selection.
My code already works but has a problem. Maybe I'll spent some minutes to explain what I want to do:

Comment: 1. I've created post-it class composed by a TextArea and some buttons. One of these buttons is necessary to manipulate the font of the text area.
2. When a user clicks the button, a new stage is created and shown to the video: the stage contains a scene with buttons and combo boxes to manipulate font weight, posture, underline, family, size and others. With the use of a simple pane, I've included a preview of the phrase "Hello world" with the manipulated font.

Comment: 3. When the user clicks on the underline toggle button, the procedure explained above starts and the preview is correctly shown on the stage.
4. If I confirm all the selected options, the stage is closed and the options are applied on the post-it text.
5. Now, the user clicks the font options button again: I wish the stage is loaded with all the previous configuration.
In this context, the only problem is represented by the underline property, because the solution based on CSS works only if the stage was already created and all its nodes already exist.

Comment: Instead, when the user clicks on the font options button, the software is able to understand that the underline property is active. So, the relative toggle button should be selected and the preview text underlined.
However, the piece of code

 Node node = textArea.getScene().lookup("#textArea .text");  
        node.pseudoClassStateChanged(pseudoClass, newValue);

returns a NullPointerException because the lookup method can't return a node with the id specified if the stage wasn't created yet.
I wish to substitute that piece of code with:

Comment: textArea.getTextNode().setUnderline(true)
   
or something like that, and totally stop using the pseudoClass.
I hope that my english won't prevent you to help me :)
Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description in the question comments, I would recommend the following.

Create a custom `TextArea` that looks something like this:

```
public class CustomTextArea extends TextArea {

    private static final PseudoClass UNDERLINED = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("underlined");

    private final BooleanProperty underlined = new SimpleBooleanProperty(this, "underlined") {
        @Override
        protected void invalidated() {
            pseudoClassStateChanged(UNDERLINED, get()); // update PseudoClass state to match 
                                                        // the current value of the property
        }
    };

    // property access methods

    public final void setUnderlined(boolean underlined) {
        this.underlined.set(underlined);
    }

    public final boolean isUnderlined() {
        return underlined.get();
    }

    public final BooleanProperty underlinedProperty() {
        return underlined;
    }

    // constructor      

    public CustomTextArea(String text, boolean underlined) {
        super(text);
        setUnderlined(underlined);
        getStyleClass().add("custom-text-area"); // to allow specific CSS styling
    }

}
```

Then in your CSS you would do:

```
.custom-text-area .text {
    -fx-underline: false;
}

.custom-text-area:underlined .text {
    -fx-underline: true;
}
```

The CSS is set on any `Text` node that is a descendant of a`CustomTextArea`.
The first CSS rule (the one without ":underlined") may not even be necessary since the default of `-fx-underline` for a `Text` node is `false`.

Then to query whether or not the text is underlined is a simple matter of calling `area.isUnderlined()` where `area` is an instance of `CustomTextArea`.

To maintain the correct visual state you could bind the `underlined` property of the `CustomTextArea` bidirectionally to the `selected` property of a `ToggleButton`. When one changes the other will reflect that change.

If you want to style only a specific `CustomTextArea` then you can still give it an ID and reference it in the CSS with `#ID`.

Comment: Slaw, thank you for your support. Your solution works!